# What is the best way to use Total to get percentage of groups in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

In excel and other similar software you can use total to get the percentage. Can anyone tell what is the most efficient way to replicate total function.

I have used nested query but I am not getting right result

```
select retpre04recency,
count(*) as CustomerCount,
(select count(*) from extractsummary) as Total,
round(count(*)/(select count(*) from extractsummary),2) as CustomerCount
    from extractsummary
    group by retpre04recency
    order by retpre04recency asc
    ;
```

My result in percentage column is zero. can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type problem. The expression

```
count(*)
```

results in type `bigint`. The expression

```
(select count(*) from extractsummary)
```

also results in type `bigint`. Unlike some programming languages (e.g. R), the division operator in PostgreSQL does not automatically promote integer operands to a fractional type. So you must cast it yourself.

```
select
    retpre04recency,
    count(*) as CustomerCount,
    (select count(*) from extractsummary) as Total,
    round(count(*)::numeric/(select count(*) from extractsummary),2) as CustomerCount
from
    extractsummary
group by
    retpre04recency
order by
    retpre04recency asc
;
```

---

Example:

```
drop table if exists extractsummary;
create table extractsummary (retpre04recency int);
insert into extractsummary (retpre04recency) values (1), (1), (2), (2), (2), (3), (3), (3), (3), (4), (4), (4), (5), (5), (5), (5), (5), (6), (6), (6), (99);

select
    retpre04recency,
    count(*) as CustomerCount,
    (select count(*) from extractsummary) as Total,
    round(count(*)::numeric/(select count(*) from extractsummary),2) as CustomerCount
from
    extractsummary
group by
    retpre04recency
order by
    retpre04recency asc
;
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks! works!
Also is this the most efficient way to do this? I mean nested query for total

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what problems you are having, but analytic functions are a simpler method than subqueries:

```
select retpre04recency,
       count(*) as CustomerCount,
       sum(count(*)) over ()  as Total,
       round(count(*)/sum(count(*)) over (), 2) as CustomerCount
from extractsummary
group by retpre04recency
order by retpre04recency asc
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes I compared both of the queries. Subquery takes around 260ms and analytics function takes around 190ms

Comment: Not exactly a tutorial, but the docs are pretty good: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tutorial-window.html. Might also find http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-window.html useful.

Answer (score 1):

The division you do is an integer division. In order to get fractional output, you should cast one of the counts to a float, like this:

```
round(cast(count(*) as numeric)/(select count(*) from extractsummary),2)
```

or short-hand:

```
round(count(*)::numeric/(select count(*) from extractsummary),2)
```

Comment: Thanks! works without rounding. The error is "function round(double precision, integer) does not exist:"

How can I do rounding

Comment: Ah, cast to numeric instead of float then. Updated my answer accordingly. Sorry about that.